# One Class classification using Kernel Density Estimate

Tags: kernel-smoothing, similarities, anomaly-detection, one-class

I have a dataset of customers who belong to one-class (say C1).
I have another data set of customers (C2) and I need to find out how similar are these to customers in C1.

This is what I have tried so far -
1. One-Class SVM in R (e1071). However, it does not support probabilities for OneClass.
2. Based on a suggestion from a similar question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582916/one-class-svm-probability-estimates-and-what-is-the-different-between-one-class/14685318#14685318) - I tried to build a non parametric model of the single class data using the kernel density estimation. And since my data set has both numerical and categorical data, I am using the np package in R.

My question is -
Can we (does it make sense to) use the generated DENSITIES as a measure to classify customers? i.e., fit a kernel density estimate to Class C1.
Now, estimate density of each customer from the data set C2 and if the density of the customer is say within min and max densities of C1 then classify it as belonging to class C1 else reject it?

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: Why would you consider this as a problem?

Comment: If I go ahead and use this technique, how would I know if the features I am using are sufficient or say how do I measure performance?